# By default not redirecting to Index action method of controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, url-routing

Recently I've created on controller call `DashboardVideos` and an action method called `Index`.

And after `Add` Or `Update`, I'm redirecting it to Index page using

`RedirectToAction("Index", "DashboardVideos")`.

but this code redirecting it to `/DashboardVideos/` and it says

**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.**

so the issue is by default it's supposed to load `Index` page when I say `/Dashboard` 
But its not, same url pattern working with all other controller (So I don't think there's anything wrong with routing pattern).

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
 public class DashboardVideosController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IDashboardVideosComponent socialTagComponent;

        public DashboardVideosController()
        {
            socialTagComponent = ComponentFactory.Get<IDashboardVideosComponent>();
        }

        // GET: DashboardVideos
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUpdate(DashboardVideosModel socialTagChannel)
    {
       //Save data to database
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "DashboardVideos");
    }
     }
```

Comment: Have you set up any custom routes for your new controller? If so, could you post them?

Comment: Nope, its using default one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write this if both actions are in same controller.

```
public ActionResult AddUpdate(DashboardVideosModel socialTagChannel)
{
   //Save data to database
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Nope, its not working, I've tried this earlier but no luck,

Simply I've pasted a link in browser `http://localhost/DashboardVideos`, but its always throw above error

Comment: Actually this path is considered as Directory.

Comment: Yes but why so, any idea, I've 8 more controllers and each of them has Index method, and its working fine with all the 8 controllers.

Comment: You must have a Folder with name DashBoardVideos.

Comment: That's it!, that was the issue, actually I created a folder DashboardVideos to save videos, but that was in sub directories`(e.g. localhost/folder1/folder2/DashboardVideos)` while controller is on root level `(e.g. localhost/DashboardVideos)`, still it was a conflict, why so ?

Comment: I think routes are same for controller and folder. i.e http://localhost/somefolder/otherfolder/DashboardVideos

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at your "RouteConfig" class and you can specify custom routes there. Also It is possible if the call comes from AJAX it can go directly to action without redirecting. Did you tried to Debug the code?